# Which trade deals with extractor fan ducting?

Tags: exhaust-fan, uk, damp

We're getting a lot of damp around the extractor fan, and I'd like the flexible ducting (in the loft) to be replaced with rigid ducting - does anyone know which trade deals with extractor fan ducting?

The extractor is behaving as expected (so probably not an electrician?), but plumbers don't seem interested either...

I *think* the ducting is the problem as it's taped to the exit point in the roof, there are peaks and troughs in the ducting, and the ducting is over 1.5m in length. We're in a new build as well, but the developer (obviously) cut some corners.

[image: Image of a damp ceiling around an extractor fan]

The ducting on the left is the one causing damp in the room below (our en-suite, for context). When we moved in, both were taped to the exit point and I fitted the jubilee clip in the hope that it would stop the damp. I've also taped the ducting to the beam to stop it from being on the floor and collecting water...

[image: Image of ducting in a loft]

[image: Another image of ducting in a loft]

Comment: Can you provide some pictures of the duct work to be replaced?

Comment: Have you investigated whether the source of the damp might be condensation, either on the interior or the exterior of the duct, rather than liquid water entering from outdoors? A solution for condensation is likely different to a solution for outdoor liquid entry.

Comment: You got yourself up there but aren't willing to take the next step? Rigid duct isn't black magic. Get some elbows and some straight sections and sheet metal screws and get to it. It's helpful to have more parts options than you think you'll need available in case plans change. Return the rest.

Comment: Yup, pretty much - that's why I needed to know which trade deals with ducting... I could do it myself, but then it's on me if something goes wrong, or is made worse. My approach / solution might also not be correct, which is why getting a tradesman in to fix it would be a more sensible option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HVAC stands for Heating Ventilation and Air Conditioning.

Ventilation would include extractor fans and their ducting.

Ducting is also important for air based heating and cooling so a lot of that knowledge would apply to extraction fans.

Comment: While that's true, we don't have many domestic HVAC people in the UK.  We have heating engineers (plumbers for wet heating systems), and air conditioning engineers (people who install mini split A/C units) but relatively few houses have ductwork aside from maybe an extractor fan. It's becoming more common on new builds due to MVHR so maybe ventilation people would be worth looking for.  Ducted air is more common in industrial settings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specialty for this here in the UK. I would suggest contacting either a general builder as they can refer to the proper specialist if there is one, or maybe a roofer, given that this is likely related to the sealing around the exit.